# change font size of symbols in word document via vba codes

Tags: vba, excel

I am transporting data from excel to word using vba and I am adding symbols/indent in my word document, however, I need help with the font size for one of the symbols I am assigning.

How I declare it now will make all the font size 10.5 but I want to change font size of symbol `ws3.Range("N1") = ChrW(&H2588)` to 5 only. It is the symbol of black square. See picture for difference, top one is 10.5 and below is what I need, size of 5.

The reason I am doing it since I have multiple of this symbols which adds up time on editing the document so I hope to revise my codes to achieve the desire results. So I want to have the symbol populated onto word document with a size of 5 instead of 10.5, the rest should stay with font size of 10.5

If you are familiar with character number, please share the character number for ChrW(&H2588).

This would work if I can just change the character number.

```
  InsertSymbol Font:="Symbol", CharacterNumber:=183, Unicode:=False
```

My codes,

```
ws3.Range("N1") = ChrW(&H2588)
.Font.Size = 10.5
.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
'deleting extra spacing
.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 0
.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
.TypeText Space(27)
.TypeText ws3.Range("N1") & Space(5) & ws3.Range("N2")
```

Methods tried,

(1) codes went through and nothing happened

```
 ws3.Range("N1").Font.Size = 5
```

(2) codes went through and nothing happened

```
With ws3.Range("N1")
.Font.Size = 5
End With
```

(3) object does not support the method

```
With ws3.Range("N1")
 .Words(1).Font.Size = 5
End With
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect you need to change the size of the character *after placing it in MS Word*. But in case it works in Excel first try `.Characters(1).Font.Size = 5` in the 3rd example.

Comment: Excel has the symbol generated with font size of 5 but after generating the word document, its back to font size 10.5 And I just tried your method, codes now pass through without issues but still populating with font size of 10.5

Comment: So you'll need to identify and adjust in Word.

Comment: I used find and replace with change of font size. it works just one more step in word document. Thanks